# Разница в запуске приложения на эмуляторе и телефоне

Tags: android, firebase

При загрузке изображений в моей программе на эмуляторе Android Studio все работает корректно, я вижу загруженное изображение, оно появляется в Storage, и корректно отображается в приложении на эмуляторе. Но при запуске на реальном устройстве изображение загружается в Storage но в приложении не отображается. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Нашлось решение проблемы заменив в коде:
map.put("imageURL", mUri); на
map.put("imageUrl", mUri);
Не совсем понятно почему прокатывало только на эмуляторе, но теперь работает и там и там.